# Need help to go through the proof of $\dfrac{a^n+b^n}{(ab)^{n-1}+1}$ is perfect $n^{th}$ power of an integer on AOPS

Tags: number-theory

This question will go to details in the proof on AOPS page at:
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h349211

This may be the only formal proof i see on web about this problem.

My question is: the proof in the case $k > a^n$ does not make sense to me: It stated that $b^{n-1}(b-ka^{n-1})\ge b^{n-1}$. Basically this means $b-ka^{n-1} \ge 1$ but Why?

From the assumption $k > a^n$ and $k = \dfrac{a^n+b^n}{(ab)^{n-1}+1}$ we know that $\dfrac{a^n+b^n}{(ab)^{n-1}+1} > a^n \implies a^n+b^n > a^{2n-1}b^{n-1}+a^n \implies b^n > a^{2n-1}b^{n-1} \implies b > a^{2n-1} \implies b-a^{2n-1} \ge 1$.

We know that by assumption in this case, $k > a^n$, so $b-ka^{n-1} < b - a^{2n-1}$. Yes $b-a^{2n-1} \ge 1$, but how do we know $b-ka^{n-1} \ge 1$ since it is smaller than $b - a^{2n-1}$?

And in the case $k < a^n$, it stated $\dfrac{a^n-k}{b^{n-1}}< a$, how is this got?

I might have other questions in the rest of the proof but this blocks me totally to understand it at this point.

Any help? Thanks...

Comment: 1) Because $  0 < k - a^n = b^{n-1} ( b  - ka^{n-1} )$. So the term in parenthesis has to be positive. $\quad$ 2) It would help if you label the questions vs your details/explanations (esp those that still end with a question mark). $\quad$ 3) Because $ a < b$ by assumption, so $( a ^n - k ) / b^{n-1} < a^n / a^{n-1} = a$. $\quad$ 4) Yes the solution writer didn't write out each of the explicit steps that they took, and expected the reader to tease it out.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks. Your comment addressed my questions very well.